# Estimate of the number of homographs in english

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, homonymy, word-sense-disambiguation

Am curious as to the number of homographs (sets of word meanings that share a common spelling) that occur in the English language. Also what the current state of the art would be for automatically differentiating senses.

The [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) project makes available a word vector model with a 2.2 million vocabulary based on 840 billion tokens (taken from the [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/) dataset] - unfortunately from my understanding there model takes no account of homographs and I'm firstly trying to get a feel for how much of an effect that would have, and secondly thinking of how to go about recreating a similar model using word senses instead of words.

Comment: Is "hard" one or not? (goes to the question of counting meanings)

Comment: well 'hard' surfaces, and 'hard' problems shouldn't be using the same word vector in my view

Comment: True *homographs* have different origins.  If you really just mean common spellings then you should call them *polysemous words* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [this Wikipedia page on English homographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_homographs) as it stands lists 164,  as the following paper title suggests: [University of Alberta norms of relative
meaning frequency for 566 homographs](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/bf03202766.pdf) there are substantially more, the same paper referencing other studies finding as much as 44% of randomly sampled words forms have multiple meaning (and 85% of the most common words in the language).

According to the University of Alberta study

> *many of the homographs in our
>   list have more than two meanings; nearly half (230) have
>   three or more meanings, and 75 have four or more meanings*

as to using separated word senses to build word vector models - [according to this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-kinds-of-related-words-that-Word2Vec-outputs/answer/Ajit-Rajasekharan#) something close to the state of the art (published 2015) can be found in the paper [Breaking Sticks and Ambiguities with Adaptive Skip-gram](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07257) which describes the AdaGram model that from my limited understanding estimates and differentiates word senses as it builds the model with similar computation requirements to word2vec.